# VS 2013 Word Add-in: Missing Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-word, add-in

I created a new VS 2013 Word 2010 Add-in, but it is missing references to **Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities** and cannot compile. I have installed the Office 2010 Tools for VS 2013, but this assembly still isn't in the GAC.

So, my question is where do I get this reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the Microsoft Office Developer Tools and re-installing via the Microsoft Web Platform Installer solved this issue for me.